# Vba to trigger 'pointerdown' event on an html element

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, automation, mouseevent

Need help to trigger 'pointerdown' event on an html element as part of a webpage automation project in excel vba.

Have been able to successfully automate using 'mousedown' trigger but recently the webpage source code has been modified to use 'pointerdown' to trigger instead of 'mousedown'.

Existing 'mousedown' code:

```
Set e1 = IE.Document.createEvent("MouseEvent")
e1.initMouseEvent "mousedown", True, True, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, True, False, False, False, 0, Null
ElementCol.Item(i).dispatchEvent e1
```

Tried the following 'pointerdown' code, but excel is throwing 'Automation error' on initPointerEvent line:

```
Set e1 = IE.Document.createEvent("PointerEvent")
e1.initPointerEvent "pointerdown", True, True, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, False, False, False, False, 0, Null , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, "", 0, False
ElementCol.Item(i).dispatchEvent e1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the url?